# To find $g(-x)$ as $g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

$$f'(x)=1+af(x)+bf^2(x)$$

$a$ and $b$ are constants

$f(0)=0$

I proved that

$$f(x+h)=\frac{f(x)+f(h)+af(x)f(h)}{1-bf(x)f(h)}$$

If we put $h=-x$

$$f(-x)=-\cfrac{f(x)}{1+af(x)}$$

$a$ and $b$ and $c$ are constants

$g(0)=0$

$$g'(x)=1+ag(x)+bg^2(x)+cg^3(x)$$

Is it possible  to find $g(-x)$ as $g(x)$ ?

Thanks

Best Regards

Note: I used the way to prove $f(x+h)$ as shown in [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292125/to-get-addition-formula-of-tan-x-via-analytic-methods).

But the same method does not work for $g(x+h)$

Thus I tried power series

$$g(x+h)=g(x)+hg'(x)+\frac{h^2g''(x)}{2!}+\frac{h^3g'''(x)}{3!}+ \dots$$

If $x=0$ and $h=-x$
$$g(-x)=g(0)-xg'(0)+\frac{x^2g''(0)}{2!}-\frac{x^3g'''(0)}{3!}+ \dots$$

If $x=0$ and $h=x$
$$g(x)=g(0)+xg'(0)+\frac{x^2g''(0)}{2!}+\frac{x^3g'''(0)}{3!}+ \dots$$

$$g''(x)=(1+ag(x)+bg^2(x)+cg^3(x))(a+2bg(x)+3cg^2(x))$$

$$g'''(x)=(1+ag(x)+bg^2(x)+cg^3(x))(a+2bg(x)+3cg^2(x))^2+(1+ag(x)+bg^2(x)+cg^3(x))^2(2b+6cg(x))$$

$$g(-x)=-x+\frac{x^2 a}{2!}-\frac{x^3(a^2+2b)}{3!}+ \dots$$

$$g(x)=x+\frac{x^2a}{2!}+\frac{x^3(a^2+2b)}{3!}+ \dots$$

I will update If I find more terms

Comment: How did you prove the formula for $f(x+h)$? what happens when you try the same ideas on $g(x+h)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried but not worked.

Comment: Is it obvious that the formula for $f(x+h)$ holds?

Comment: @Did Yes i proved it